# How to do post-processing of video saved by Red5 media server

Tags: post, video, red5

I have a use case, where in after sending the video stream to the Red5 server, I would like to post process on the video after the video is saved. I would like to add some metadata tags on them.

I found that this can be done in appDisconnect() method in the ApplicationAdapter, but there are other ways via which the video can be saved like by using ClientBroadcastStream also.

Example

```
ClientBroadcastStream stream = (ClientBroadcastStream) app.getBroadcastStream(
    conn.getScope(), "hostStream");
// Stop recording
stream.stopRecording();
```

I would like to know if there are any events which I can listen on (like which tells me that video is saved and is saved in this location with this filename) to do post-processing of the video. So that I need not put hooks in multiple places.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "ez" way is to implement your own ClientBroadcastStream by extending this base class. Then simply override the "stopRecording()" method. If you would like to take a moment and add an enhancement request on the issue tracker, I would be glad to look into adding scope events for this type of thing. With a scope event you could just listen for them anywhere and handle them appropriately. Red5 issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/list

Using a custom stream class would be configured in the red5-common.xml like so:

```
<bean id="clientBroadcastStream" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true" class="com.mypackage.MyClientBroadcastStream">
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Mondian, Thanks for the reply. I would like to know what would be the bean definition to be added in the red5-web.xml, so that this POJO would be used.

Comment: You would need to add your bean to the red5/conf/red5-common.xml file. The class / pojo would have to be placed in a jar within red5/lib to be found by the server. CBS is at the bottom of the file.

Comment: This works. But this change would be applicable to all the apps in this red5 server. I would like this class to be used only by specific apps in my red5 server. Can you please let me know how can I localize this to a specific project.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible in the current codebase; If you want to enter an enhancement request on the issues list, I could look into it.